# making a ball Jump a fixed distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

```c#
void Update ()
{
    Vector3 input = new Vector3 (0, 0, 1);
    Vector3 direction = input.normalized;
    Vector3 velocity = direction * speed;
    Vector3 moveAmount = velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position += moveAmount;

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
    {
        player.AddForce (Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Since `Time.deltaTime` varies `moveAmount` also varies for every jump making the distance of the jump vary slightly.

The ball is to jump between blocks separated by a fixed gap and therefore the above behaviour causes problems.

Is there any way I can fix this and make fixed length jumps?

Comment: There is no guarantee a rigidbody force will always b the-same. To reduce the different in the jump distance, remove the `Time.deltaTime` from your jump distance. You don't need that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CharacterController for this. Make sure you have a CharacterController and Collider attached to your gameobject. Also if you have a rigibody attached to your game object it may cause it to behave unexpectedly so you might have to contraint it.

```
public CharacterController controller;

private float verticalVelocity;
private float gravity = 25.0f;
private float jumpForce = 15.0f;

void Awake () {
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update () {

    if( controller == null )
        return;

    if( controller.isGrounded)
    {
        verticalVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        if( Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) )
        {
            verticalVelocity = jumpForce;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }   

    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");    

    Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
    moveVector.x = moveHorizontal * 5.0f;
    moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;
    moveVector.z = moveVertical * 5.0f;
    controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Check this tutorial for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miMCu5796KM